# regarding compareTo() method in java

Tags: java

I am very confused about the working principle of the `compareTo()` method in Java. On passing a list through `Collections.sort()` method, which objects are actually get compared to return the negative or positive or zero value?

Comment: Please refer [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754490/using-compareto-and-collections-sort)

Comment: Did you [read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-)?

Comment: All of them. You need to look at all values to sort a list (just not necessarily compare everything to everything else).

Comment: You sort a list so you compare the elements of that list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compareTo method java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017381/compareto-method-java)

Answer (score 0):

It is used for sorting. So all elements get compared and It is ultimately used for sorting.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html Here is an example.

Answer (score 0):

All of them, and most of them several times.  Your question is really *"How does sorting work"*, which is too broad for StackOverflow.

However, a simplified answer is that the algorithm compares pairs of elements, each time invoking `compareTo()`, to decide which one is "smaller" (for some definition of "smaller").  Good sorting algorithms try to minimize the number of comparisons, but each element will have to be compared to some number of others (where that number is normally > 1).

The reason `compareTo()` exists is that it allows YOU to decide what "smaller" and "greater" mean for your objects, allowing you to sort them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Say your list is a `List<Integer>` with the values `[5, 7, 3]`. `Integer` has a `compareTo()`.

The exact method of sorting depends on the algorithm, but lets try a simple bubblesort.

- `5.compareTo(7)` < 0: No action necessary
- `7.compareTo(3)` > 0: Swap elements

List is now `[5, 3, 7]`.

- `3.compareTo(5)` > 0: Swap elements

List is now `[3, 5, 7]`, and sort has been completed.

In this particular example, all elements ended up being compared to all other elements. This is rarely the case, since smart sorting algorithms can minimize the number of comparisons necessary.