# Using collections.sort() with compareTo, not sorting

Tags: java, class

So currently I'm working on an assignment where I have to two classes, one is named Fysiker and the other Human. Fysiker is simply an extension of the Human class. Human has two attributes: name and age while Fysiker has three: name, age and startyear. I have created an array which takes both Human and Fysiker, and I want to sort it by age first, but if two fysiker have the same age, I want it to sort by my third attribute: the startyear.

My understanding of the compareTo (I need to use compareTo, for the sake of the exercise) is limited, but from what I've read it's a comparable which interacts automatically with the Collections.sort(), my code currently looks like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Fysiker extends Human{

    public int startyear;
    public Fysiker(int age, String name, int startyear){
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
        this.startyear=startyear;
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return startyear;
    }
    public int compareTo(Fysiker o){
        int b;
        b=(this.age>o.age ? 1:this.age<o.age ? -1:0);
        if (b==0){
            b=(this.startyear>o.startyear ? 1:this.startyear<o.startyear ? -1:0);
            return b;}
            else{
            return b;}

    }
    public String toString(){
        return "åldern är:"+this.age+" "+"namnet är:"+this.name+" "+"började fysik:"+String.format("F%02d",this.startyear%100);
    }

    public Fysiker(){
        this.age=15+rand.nextInt(86);
        this.name=names.get(rand.nextInt(names.size()));
        this.startyear=2015-rand.nextInt(this.age-14);
        while (this.startyear<1932){
            this.startyear=2015-rand.nextInt(this.age-14);
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Human> fysiker=new ArrayList<Human>();
        int q;


        for (q=0;q<=80;q++){
            fysiker.add(new Fysiker());
            //fysiker.add(new Human());

            //System.out.println(fysiker.get(q).toString());
        }
        int s;
        Collections.sort(fysiker);
        for (s=0;s<=fysiker.size()-1;s++){
            //fysiker.get(0).compareTo(fysiker.get(s));
            System.out.println(fysiker.get(s).toString());
            //System.out.println(fysiker.get(0));
        }
    }

}
```

the Human class in turn:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Human implements Comparable<Human>{
        public static final List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Rutger","Oscar","Aram","Noak","Hilda","Dahl");
        public Random rand=new Random();
        public String name;
        public int age;

    public Human(int age, String name){
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;

    }
    public Human(){
        this.age=rand.nextInt(101);
        this.name=names.get(rand.nextInt(names.size()));
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "åldern är:"+this.age+" "+"namnet är:"+this.name;
    }
    public int compareTo(Human o){
        return this.age-o.age;
}
}
```

My issue is that it does not sort after the startyear, but I can fix it if I remove compareTo from my Human class, but I need that one as well, I want to sort them all, but it fixes the "not sorting after startyear for the fysiker"-problem. Where do I go from here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using compareTo and Collections.sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754490/using-compareto-and-collections-sort)

Comment: You need to implement Comparable interface, override the compareTo() method with your own code, that will return negative, zero or positive depending on the outcome of comparison. You would set up if conditions inside method body that will take care of the situation when age is the same.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the method defined in the subclass :

```
public int compareTo(Fysiker o){
```

doesn't override the method in the base class :

```
public int compareTo(Human o){
```

You could define the subclass with the same signature to override effectively :

```
public int compareTo(Human o){
```

and using `instanceof` to make the comparison according to the real type.
But it would be not a good idea either.
Indeed, `Fysiker` would know how to compare `Human` and `Fysiker` but `Human` would know how to compare only `Human`s.

The [`Comparable.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) contract states that :

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:
>   ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0.

**`Comparable` should not try to be interoperable between classes as it may violate the transitivity comparison principle.**

I think that in your case, as alternative, you should use a `Comparator` to sort elements.

You have two ways.

1) If the list contains only `Fysiker` instances, declare a `List` of `Fysiker` and create a `Comparator<Fysiker>` :

```
List<Fysiker> fysiker = new ArrayList<Fysiker>();
...
Collections.sort(fysiker);
```

It limits the type of the elements that the List may accept but it is wished in this specific case.

2) If the list contains both `Human` and `Fysiker` instances, declare a `List` of `Human` and create a `Comparator<Human>` :

```
List<Human> humans = new ArrayList<Human>();
...
Collections.sort(fysiker);
```

In the `Comparator` implementation, you should check the type of the instances and compare them according to :

```
public class ComparatorHumanAndFysiker implements Comparator<Human>{

      public int compare(Human o1, Human o2){

           if (o1 instanceof Fysiker && o2 instanceof Fysiker){
              Fysiker f1 = (Fysiker) o1;
              Fysiker f2 = (Fysiker) o2;
              // specific comparison
              return ...;
           }

            // else mixed type comparison or human comparison              
            return o1.age - o2.age;                         
        }
 }
```

Comment: How would you sort a `List<Human>` using a `Comparator<Fysiker>`?

Comment: But the OP wants to sort a `List` that hods both `Human` and `Fysiker` instances? Why not use a `Comparator<Human>`?

Comment: Not sure. Actually, the list contains only `Fysiker`. If it was really required, I assume that  providing a `Comparator<Human>` that handles both types with an `instanceof` is a way. It is not a perfect solution but a workaround for a very specific requirement.

Comment: I am not sure that the list only contains `Fysiker`. Read the comment in the code *"//fysiker.add(new Human());"*... Yes a `Comparatpr<Human>` with `instanceof` is the only possible solution..

Comment: So the suggestion would be to start looking into Comparators?

Comment: @AndersAndersson Yes. If you want to do it the right way without breaking rules. Otherwise a `Comparable` with an `instanceof` check would do just fine..

Comment: Comparable with instanceof check is exactly what I want to do, but I dont know how to implement it...

Comment: I want more on how exactly transitivity will get violated. You can compare `human1`, `human2` and `human3` with each other satisfying transitivity. Same with  `{fysiker1, fysiker2, fysiker3}`. This is considering that there is no `compareTo` in `fysiker`. I tried basic code [here](https://pastebin.com/dB6V6P7C). Not able to figure out how should I code to violate transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

During the sort, only the `compareTo(Human o)` method is used. The `compareTo(Fysiker o)` is never used since you are not implementing `Comparable<Fysiker>` interface. Unfortunately with your concrete class inheritance your `Fysiker` class wont be able to implement `Comparable<Fysiker>` because it already indirectly implements `Comparable<Human>` interface and in Java  you cant implement same interface with different generic types.

As a quick workaround you can override `compareTo(Human o)` in your `Fysiker` class instead of defining an overloaded `compareTo(Fysiker o)` method:

```
public int compareTo(Human o){
    int b;
    b=(this.age>o.age ? 1:this.age<o.age ? -1:0);

    if (b==0 && o instanceof Fysiker){
        b= ( this.startyear> ( (Fysiker) o ).startyear ? 1:this.startyear< ( (Fysiker)o ).startyear ? -1:0);
        return b;
    }else{
        return b;
    }

}
```

**Update:**

I think this approach is much cleaner:

```
public int compareTo(Human o){
        int age1 = this.age;
        int age2 = o.age;

        int result = age1 - age2;
        if (result != 0) return result;

        int startyear1 = this.startyear;
        int startyear2 = (o instanceof Fysiker) ? ( (Fysiker)o ).startyear : 0;

        return startyear1 - startyear2;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
åldern är:0 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:5 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:6 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:6 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:7 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:8 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:10 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:12 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:14 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:15 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:15 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:16 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:17 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:17 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:18 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:18 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F2015
åldern är:18 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:18 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F2014
åldern är:19 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:19 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F2013
åldern är:19 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2015
åldern är:19 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:20 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2011
åldern är:20 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:21 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2015
åldern är:21 namnet är:Rutger
åldern är:21 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:21 namnet är:Dahl började fysik:F2009
åldern är:21 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F2009
åldern är:21 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F2015
åldern är:22 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F2011
åldern är:22 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:22 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:22 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:24 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F2006
åldern är:24 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:24 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:26 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2013
åldern är:27 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F2012
åldern är:27 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2013
åldern är:28 namnet är:Rutger
åldern är:28 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:28 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F2004
åldern är:29 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F2007
åldern är:29 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F2013
åldern är:29 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F2013
åldern är:31 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F2009
åldern är:31 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:31 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:33 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F2004
åldern är:33 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F2008
åldern är:34 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:34 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F2007
åldern är:34 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:34 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F1999
åldern är:35 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:35 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2010
åldern är:36 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:36 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:38 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F1999
åldern är:39 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F2013
åldern är:42 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:43 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:43 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F2002
åldern är:43 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:43 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:44 namnet är:Rutger
åldern är:44 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:44 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:44 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:45 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:47 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F1986
åldern är:48 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:50 namnet är:Dahl började fysik:F2004
åldern är:50 namnet är:Dahl började fysik:F2008
åldern är:50 namnet är:Rutger
åldern är:51 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2014
åldern är:52 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:54 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:56 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F2011
åldern är:56 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:56 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:56 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F2009
åldern är:58 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:59 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F1982
åldern är:59 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:60 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F1985
åldern är:60 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:60 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:61 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F1976
åldern är:61 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2003
åldern är:62 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:63 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F1989
åldern är:63 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:63 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:64 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2013
åldern är:65 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F1998
åldern är:65 namnet är:Dahl började fysik:F1998
åldern är:67 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F1968
åldern är:67 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F1972
åldern är:68 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:69 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F2007
åldern är:69 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:69 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:70 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F1977
åldern är:70 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F2000
åldern är:71 namnet är:Dahl började fysik:F1961
åldern är:71 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F2009
åldern är:72 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:73 namnet är:Dahl började fysik:F1998
åldern är:75 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:75 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:76 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:76 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F1998
åldern är:76 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:77 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:77 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:78 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F1958
åldern är:78 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:79 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F1958
åldern är:79 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F1960
åldern är:79 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F1967
åldern är:79 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:80 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F1961
åldern är:80 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F1969
åldern är:80 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F2007
åldern är:81 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F1996
åldern är:81 namnet är:Oscar
åldern är:81 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F2011
åldern är:85 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:87 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:88 namnet är:Dahl började fysik:F1976
åldern är:88 namnet är:Rutger
åldern är:88 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F1968
åldern är:88 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2003
åldern är:88 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F2005
åldern är:88 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F2005
åldern är:89 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F1970
åldern är:89 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:89 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:90 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F1975
åldern är:91 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F1984
åldern är:91 namnet är:Hilda
åldern är:91 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:91 namnet är:Aram
åldern är:92 namnet är:Rutger
åldern är:92 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F1997
åldern är:94 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F1936
åldern är:95 namnet är:Dahl
åldern är:95 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F1940
åldern är:96 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F1945
åldern är:96 namnet är:Rutger började fysik:F1962
åldern är:96 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F1994
åldern är:96 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F1997
åldern är:97 namnet är:Dahl började fysik:F1941
åldern är:97 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F1958
åldern är:97 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F2014
åldern är:98 namnet är:Oscar började fysik:F1973
åldern är:98 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2012
åldern är:99 namnet är:Noak började fysik:F1951
åldern är:100 namnet är:Noak
åldern är:100 namnet är:Dahl började fysik:F1995
```

Comment: Not sure but that solution doesnt seem to work for me, it looks very neat but it doesn't work implementing it like that, at least not for me.

Comment: That solution, it still wont sort after the startyear for Fysiker if the age of the two Fysiker is the same

Comment: Please, provide sample output showing how you want the output to be. For example this seems fine for me:

åldern är:34 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F1997 ->
åldern är:34 namnet är:Aram började fysik:F2005 ->
åldern är:34 namnet är:Hilda började fysik:F2013

Comment: My compareTo for Fysiker seem to be working fine as lone as I only compare one Fysiker against another manually, but if I create, lets say 100, it doesnt compare them, notice that this is only Fysiker I've created this time, but at some point I wanted a mixed array of both Humen and Fysiker

Comment: I added the sample output with both Human and Fysiker being sorted in the same list. Feel free to show how would you want it to look like.